# How to detect whether the incoming request to an angularjs application is a GET or POST request?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I am newbie to angularjs. I developed an angularjs application using angular seed skeleton https://github.com/angular/angular-seed for client side. And for API server I used expressjs server.

My home page url is something like localhost:9000/app/index.html#/home
So, typically if I hit the url localhost:9000/app/index.html#/home I see my home page.

But, I have a requirement that there will be a POST request also to my application from some xyz application.

So, I want to determine, whether the incoming request to my angular seed application is coming from an external application or not.

Like in PHP there is a Super global array $_SERVER, with which you can determine the incoming request method... Is there anything in angularjs to determine the request method.

I hope my question is clear enough to understand.

Truly appreciate for reading my question, some hint would be great.

Comment: Do you mean, how can you tell if a request is GET or POST to expressjs? That seems pretty straight forward - you'd check the request method for GET/POST and the referrer to see if it came from an external app.

Comment: Since you're using express, you'd just separate your routes. `app.get('/')`, `app.post('/')`.

Comment: I guess my question was not very clear... My application is running on two node server. a. the client side which is a angularjs application, running on a node server(angular seed style) and the  b. API server is running on a express server. So you can forget about the express erver.... What I want is, to determine the incoming request method to my angular seed application.

Comment: angularjs is client side and not server side. so it ideally cant receive get/post request... please change the question appropriately...

Answer (score 2):

What you are asking implies you want to use an Angular frontend to provide POST method endpoints to your API. This does not make sense.

The equivalent of PHP's $_SERVER array to get passed variables is found inside Express's API, using the `req` parameter of a specific route setup. See http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#router.route. This is where you create logic based on request method. `app.get()` and `app.post()` and `app.put()` and so on, as Ben's comment mentioned.

In the traditional PHP example you mention, the entire request goes to the server and a page result is returned to the browser, so you have the chance to detect that a POST or GET was made and direct the request appropriately.

Angular is a javascript based framework that *runs in a browser*. The browser will use GET requests to initially download all the html/js/css, but then it runs in a javascript context and no server is involved after this point unless explicitly coded in an Angular module/controller. This is where you would make GET/POST/PUT/DELETE requests *to your API backend*.

Your API is accessed with XHR (XmlHttpRequest) calls in a javascript context, based on user interaction with the UI. These calls can be made using GET or POST et al depending on how your API functions, using angular $http or $resource and the like.